# Omnet++ GUI keeps crashing

Tags: tcl, osx-mavericks, tk-toolkit, omnet++

i guess the problem was the file ~/.tkenvrc
after removing it everything was fine. Only problem was that its not deleted or reset with make clean.
It seems that it saves the current arrangement and values of the GUI

In case anybody else has this error i hope this post is of some help.

cheers

```
Initializing Global User Observer
2014-07-07 13:01:19.526 OverSim[1039:507] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-07-07 13:01:19.527 OverSim[1039:507] Error (1000) creating window shape
2014-07-07 13:01:19.527 OverSim[1039:507] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8717925c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8e5b4e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8717910c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff92d7c9d9 _NSCreateWindowWithOpaqueShape2 + 159
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff92d7ba41 -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 3720
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff92d7a717 -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] + 85
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff92d7a690 -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 29
    7   Tk                                  0x000000010482dbeb XMapWindow + 134
    8   Tk                                  0x00000001047a1afd Tk_MapWindow + 69
    9   Tk                                  0x00000001047a9e6a TkInstallFrameMenu + 271
    10  Tcl                                 0x000000010492b70d TclServiceIdle + 87
    11  Tcl                                 0x0000000104912cee Tcl_DoOneEvent + 344
    12  Tk                                  0x00000001047a9e57 TkInstallFrameMenu + 252
    13  Tcl                                 0x000000010492b70d TclServiceIdle + 87
    14  Tcl                                 0x0000000104912cee Tcl_DoOneEvent + 344
    15  Tk                                  0x0000000104783760 TkGetDisplayOf + 972
    16  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    17  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    18  Tcl                                 0x000000010491fdea TclObjInterpProcCore + 699
    19  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    20  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a9d9d Tcl_EvalEx + 1838
    21  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ab030 Tcl_VarEvalVA + 147
    22  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ab0fb Tcl_VarEval + 148
    23  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010392092a _ZN19TGraphicalModWindow12createWindowEv + 194
    24  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x0000000103900bef _ZN5Tkenv7inspectEP7cObjectiPKcPv + 529
    25  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010392fe24 _ZN21cInspectByNameVisitor5visitEP7cObject + 392
    26  liboppsimd.dylib                    0x0000000103debb53 _ZN11cSimulation12forEachChildEP8cVisitor + 63
    27  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010392fe5c _ZN21cInspectByNameVisitor5visitEP7cObject + 448
    28  liboppsimd.dylib                    0x0000000103dfd07b _ZN8cVisitor7processEP7cObject + 47
    29  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010392ec5d _Z19inspectObjectByNamePKcS0_iS0_ + 85
    30  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x0000000103914d14 _Z17inspectByName_cmdPvP10Tcl_InterpiPPKc + 264
    31  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a7786 TclInvokeStringCommand + 124
    32  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    33  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    34  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ecdbc Tcl_ExprObj + 38935
    35  Tcl                                 0x00000001048aa73f TclEvalObjEx + 422
    36  Tcl                                 0x00000001048b2fa4 TclDumpMemoryInfo + 19667
    37  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    38  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    39  Tcl                                 0x000000010491fdea TclObjInterpProcCore + 699
    40  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    41  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    42  Tcl                                 0x000000010491fdea TclObjInterpProcCore + 699
    43  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    44  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a9d9d Tcl_EvalEx + 1838
    45  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ab030 Tcl_VarEvalVA + 147
    46  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ab0fb Tcl_VarEval + 148
    47  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x0000000103900f16 _ZN5Tkenv16updateInspectorsEv + 426
    48  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x0000000103900970 _ZN5Tkenv6newRunEPKci + 566
    49  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010390cebd _Z10newRun_cmdPvP10Tcl_InterpiPPKc + 126
    50  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a7786 TclInvokeStringCommand + 124
    51  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    52  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    53  Tcl                                 0x000000010491fdea TclObjInterpProcCore + 699
    54  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    55  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a9d9d Tcl_EvalEx + 1838
    56  Tcl                                 0x00000001048aa54e Tcl_Eval + 39
    57  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x00000001038fec16 _ZN5Tkenv3runEv + 1788
    58  liboppenvird.dylib                  0x0000000103a4c20e _ZN9EnvirBase3runEiPPcP14cConfiguration + 414
    59  liboppenvird.dylib                  0x0000000103a48ee2 _Z18setupUserInterfaceiPPc + 2570
    60  liboppenvird.dylib                  0x0000000103a49e51 evMain + 81
    61  OverSim                             0x0000000100832855 main + 32
    62  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8a8435fd start + 1
)
2014-07-07 13:01:19.528 OverSim[1039:507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1000) creating window shape'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8717925c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8e5b4e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8717910c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff92d7c9d9 _NSCreateWindowWithOpaqueShape2 + 159
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff92d7ba41 -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 3720
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff92d7a717 -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] + 85
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff92d7a690 -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 29
    7   Tk                                  0x000000010482dbeb XMapWindow + 134
    8   Tk                                  0x00000001047a1afd Tk_MapWindow + 69
    9   Tk                                  0x00000001047a9e6a TkInstallFrameMenu + 271
    10  Tcl                                 0x000000010492b70d TclServiceIdle + 87
    11  Tcl                                 0x0000000104912cee Tcl_DoOneEvent + 344
    12  Tk                                  0x00000001047a9e57 TkInstallFrameMenu + 252
    13  Tcl                                 0x000000010492b70d TclServiceIdle + 87
    14  Tcl                                 0x0000000104912cee Tcl_DoOneEvent + 344
    15  Tk                                  0x0000000104783760 TkGetDisplayOf + 972
    16  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    17  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    18  Tcl                                 0x000000010491fdea TclObjInterpProcCore + 699
    19  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    20  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a9d9d Tcl_EvalEx + 1838
    21  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ab030 Tcl_VarEvalVA + 147
    22  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ab0fb Tcl_VarEval + 148
    23  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010392092a _ZN19TGraphicalModWindow12createWindowEv + 194
    24  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x0000000103900bef _ZN5Tkenv7inspectEP7cObjectiPKcPv + 529
    25  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010392fe24 _ZN21cInspectByNameVisitor5visitEP7cObject + 392
    26  liboppsimd.dylib                    0x0000000103debb53 _ZN11cSimulation12forEachChildEP8cVisitor + 63
    27  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010392fe5c _ZN21cInspectByNameVisitor5visitEP7cObject + 448
    28  liboppsimd.dylib                    0x0000000103dfd07b _ZN8cVisitor7processEP7cObject + 47
    29  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010392ec5d _Z19inspectObjectByNamePKcS0_iS0_ + 85
    30  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x0000000103914d14 _Z17inspectByName_cmdPvP10Tcl_InterpiPPKc + 264
    31  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a7786 TclInvokeStringCommand + 124
    32  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    33  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    34  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ecdbc Tcl_ExprObj + 38935
    35  Tcl                                 0x00000001048aa73f TclEvalObjEx + 422
    36  Tcl                                 0x00000001048b2fa4 TclDumpMemoryInfo + 19667
    37  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    38  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    39  Tcl                                 0x000000010491fdea TclObjInterpProcCore + 699
    40  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    41  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    42  Tcl                                 0x000000010491fdea TclObjInterpProcCore + 699
    43  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    44  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a9d9d Tcl_EvalEx + 1838
    45  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ab030 Tcl_VarEvalVA + 147
    46  Tcl                                 0x00000001048ab0fb Tcl_VarEval + 148
    47  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x0000000103900f16 _ZN5Tkenv16updateInspectorsEv + 426
    48  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x0000000103900970 _ZN5Tkenv6newRunEPKci + 566
    49  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x000000010390cebd _Z10newRun_cmdPvP10Tcl_InterpiPPKc + 126
    50  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a7786 TclInvokeStringCommand + 124
    51  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    52  Tcl                                 0x00000001048e8d6a Tcl_ExprObj + 22469
    53  Tcl                                 0x000000010491fdea TclObjInterpProcCore + 699
    54  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a8ab6 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1503
    55  Tcl                                 0x00000001048a9d9d Tcl_EvalEx + 1838
    56  Tcl                                 0x00000001048aa54e Tcl_Eval + 39
    57  libopptkenvd.dylib                  0x00000001038fec16 _ZN5Tkenv3runEv + 1788
    58  liboppenvird.dylib                  0x0000000103a4c20e _ZN9EnvirBase3runEiPPcP14cConfiguration + 414
    59  liboppenvird.dylib                  0x0000000103a48ee2 _Z18setupUserInterfaceiPPc + 2570
    60  liboppenvird.dylib                  0x0000000103a49e51 evMain + 81
    61  OverSim                             0x0000000100832855 main + 32
    62  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8a8435fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: So… what is the question?

Comment: there is none i'm afraid. but i want to save those with the same error a lot of trouble. took me nearly a day to figure this out. i i'd have closed the thread if i knew how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OMNET++ Tkenv/GUI doesn't appear anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961937/omnet-tkenv-gui-doesnt-appear-anymore)