# OMNET++ Tkenv/GUI doesn't appear anymore

Tags: omnet++

I'm using OMNET++ since two weeks and everything was working pretty good until I run a simulation a couple of minutes ago and the simulation Tkenv window doesn't appear anymore ?

Any idea about this bug ?

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful to know the sequence of steps you took to get to this stage, so those who use OMNET++ can replicate it and see if it happens on their set up as well.

Comment: I picked a random network like the tictoc one for exemple, I go into the omnetpp.ini file and I run the simulation.

The small icon of the Tkenv GUI appears in the tool bar, not the entire window

Comment: which operating system are you using for OMNeT++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tkenv stores the last used window layout in a file ".tkenvrc" in the directory containing your simulation. Maybe deleting this file (thus restoring the default layout) helps.